# How do I eliminate unwanted redirects on a web page?

Tags: browser, redirection, browser-cache

I have been accessing a particular web site over a period of months. Over the last two days, every time I try to access the site, I see the site page for less than a second, and then get redirected to something called blogbar.org. As far as I am concerned this is a malicious redirect, that is preventing me accessing a site I find invaluable.

How do I reestablish access to the required site.

I have virus and spyware scanned my machine, and it is reported clean. I have cleared my cache and browsing information from my browser (Chrome), without effect. I have examined the source code of the page to which I am redirected, to find it is very extensive, and is full of URLs which have (the maximum?) a very large amount of binary information attached to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox you can try enabling the following setting under Options > Advanced > General > "Warn me when web sites try to redirect or reload the page."

The fact that you do at least see the site for a split second would suggest that it is not a server-side redirect, but possibly performed in script, so disabling JavaScript might work, or installing the NoScript browser extension.

You can also disable META REFRESH in IE under Internet options > Security > Custom level... > Miscellaneous

It is possible that the site itself has been hacked, so there not necessarily anything malicious on your machine that is performing the redirect.

Comment: The Firefox option is not available (AFAIK) in Chrome. Disabling Javascript does enable me to access the site, but then presents me with problems on this and other Stack Overflow sites - I cannot log in by my normal method - using my Facebook login.

Comment: Installing NoScript and setting up appropriate permissions on that extension provides a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling javascript in your browser

Comment: Disabling Javascript does enable me to access the site, but then presents me with problems on this and other Stack Overflow sites - I cannot log in by my normal method - using my Facebook login.

Comment: I'd try to email the admins, tell them they've been hit with an XSS attack.

Comment: Though I did not mention XSS I have informed the site owner.